# Typeerror takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this may be a dumb question, but I am having a difficult time figuring out the error.
I created a class called User to print out the first and last name, that's it. But when I try running it, it's giving me a typerror.

```
class User():
    def _init_(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def describe_user(self):
        print("Your name is " + self.first_name.title() + ", " + self.last_name.title())
user_name = User('Andy', 'Wang')
user_name.describe_user()
```

The error is as follows:

```
File "c:\Users\Andy Wang\Documents\PCC\chap7.py", line 291, in <module>
    user_name = User('Andy', 'Wang')
TypeError: User() takes no arguments
```

I have made a similar program, but this time describing a restaurant and it works fine:

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("\nThe restaraunt is called " + self.restaurant_name.title() + ".")
        print("It serves " + self.cuisine_type.title() + " food.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(self.restaurant_name + " is open!\n")

restaraunt = Restaurant('Szechuan Ichiban', 'Chinese')
restaraunt.describe_restaurant()
restaraunt.open_restaurant()
```

So I am just confused as to why the restaurant class works but my user class does not.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite simple `__init__` has 2 underscores before and at the end. So it should be

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def describe_user(self):
        print("Your name is " + self.first_name.title() + ", " + self.last_name.title())
user_name = User('Andy', 'Wang')
user_name.describe_user()
```