# TypeError: TestSmoke() takes no arguments

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run two test cases, however I am getting an error message TypeError: TestSmoke() takes no arguments

Here is my code:

```
from nose.tools import istest
from fbtests.pages import Pages
from utils.misc import selenium_testcase


@istest
@selenium_testcase
class TestSmoke:

    def test_smoke_homepage_country(self):
        """Check successful country tests from homepage

        Scenario:
        Search and assert country pages through URL

        Steps:
        1. Go to home page
        2. Search state through URL parameter
        3. Assert that country landing page is visible

        """
        pages = Pages(self.driver)
        list_of_countries = {'us', 'mx', 'mv', 'au', 'bg'}
        for country in list_of_countries:
            pages.home.visit('platform', 'homepage', '/charters/search/' + str(country))

    def test_smoke_homepage_state(self):
        """Check successful state tests from homepage

        Scenario:
        Search and assert state pages through URL

        Steps:
        1. Go to home page
        2. Search state through URL parameter
        3. Assert that state landing page is visible

        """
        pages = Pages(self.driver)
        list_of_states = {'/us/AL', '/us/FL', '/us/SC' '/mx/BS', '/au/QL', }
        for states in list_of_states:
            pages.home.visit('platform', 'homepage', '/charters/search/' + str(states))


run = TestSmoke()
run.test_smoke_homepage_country()
run.test_smoke_homepage_state()
```

If there is any other way to run two tests from one file, please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: If I add **init** i get following error: **init** is missing 1 positional argument: 'list_of_states'

Here is the edited code:

```
    from nose.tools import istest
    from fbtests.pages import Pages
    from utils.misc import selenium_testcase


@istest
@selenium_testcase
class TestSmoke:

    def __init__(self, list_of_countries, list_of_states):
        self.list_of_countries = list_of_countries
        self.list_of_states = list_of_states

    def test_smoke_homepage_country(self):
        """Check successful country tests from homepage

        Scenario:
        Search and assert country pages through URL

        Steps:
        1. Go to home page
        2. Search state through URL parameter
        3. Assert that country landing page is visible

        """
        pages = Pages(self.driver)
        list_of_countries = {'us', 'mx', 'mv', 'au', 'bg'}
        for country in list_of_countries:
            pages.home.visit('platform', 'homepage', '/charters/search/' + str(country))

    def test_smoke_homepage_state(self):
        """Check successful state tests from homepage

        Scenario:
        Search and assert state pages through URL

        Steps:
        1. Go to home page
        2. Search state through URL parameter
        3. Assert that state landing page is visible

        """
        pages = Pages(self.driver)
        list_of_states = {'/us/AL', '/us/FL', '/us/SC' '/mx/BS', '/au/QL', }
        for states in list_of_states:
            pages.home.visit('platform', 'homepage', '/charters/search/' + str(states))


run = TestSmoke()
run.test_smoke_homepage_country()
run.test_smoke_homepage_state()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried use **init** function in "TestSmoke" class? You can see an example here: [Typeerror takes no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515925/typeerror-takes-no-arguments)

Comment: i have updated an answer. I still get error :/